# System of 4 quartic equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

\begin{align*}a &=\sqrt{4+\sqrt{5+a}},\\ b &=\sqrt{4-\sqrt{5+b}},\\ c &=\sqrt{4+\sqrt{5-c}},\\ d &=\sqrt{4-\sqrt{5-d}}.\end{align*} 
Compute $abcd$.

I set up each as a quartic and got $a^4-8a^2-a+11=0$ and similar equations for $b,c,d$, but am unable to figure out how to format the roots as a product of all of them.  Could someone give me a bit of a hint?  Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We get that $a$, $b$, $-c$ and $-d$ are distinct roots of the polynomial
$$x^4-8x^2-x+11.$$
Hence,
$$x^4-8x^2-x+11=(x-a)(x-b)(x+c)(x+d)$$
so
$$abcd=11.$$

Comment: Wait, where did you get a,b,-c, and -d from?

Comment: @rk_347 As you showed, $a$ is a root of $x^4-8x^2-x+11$. Doing the same thing with $b$ yields to the same polynomial. For $c$, the same techniques gives that $c$ is a root of $x^4-8x^2+x+11$ and hence $-c$ is a root of $x^4-8x^2-x+11$. You also get this for $d$.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $a, b, c, d$ are the roots of the equation

$$(x^2 - 4)^2 = 5 + x$$

$$x^2 - 4 = \pm\sqrt{5 + x}$$
$$x^2 = 4 \pm \sqrt{5 + x}$$
$$x = 4 \pm \sqrt{5 + x}, -(4 \pm \sqrt{5 + x})$$
$$x = 4 \pm \sqrt{5 + x}, 4 \pm \sqrt{5 - x}$$

Now, the quartic equation corresponding to the first equation is, as you've expanded,

$$x^4 - 8x^2 - x + 11 = 0$$

By Vieta's Formulas, the product of the roots ($a, b, c, d$) is given by

$$abcd = (-1)^4\frac{11}{1} = 11$$